# Calling git from scheduled batch file

Tags: windows, git, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a batch file which will call some git commands. For example `test.bat` contains:

```
cd c:\path\to\my\repo
call git status
pause
```

When opening the batch file by double clicking on it, this runs as expected. However, when run from Task Scheduler, it throws the error `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin` is in my PATH environment variable.

Comment: Ah just a thought - I did only just add the path into the PATH EV... maybe I need a restart (due to EVs only being read at application startup (and assuming Task Scheduler starts at startup))

Comment: Is the scheduler running as you if not, then git might not be in the path of the user that is being used for scheduling the task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

Just needed to restart computer after editing the PATH Environment Variable.

This is because Environment Variables are only read at application startup and Task Scheduler is only started at system startup.

There may be a way of forcing it to restart which I would be interested in hearing if anybody knows.